# Is it possible to apply `border-radius` for a specific corner ?

Tags: css, cornerradius

I know that it's possible to apply border-radius commonly to an area.but now I working on a design which contain different values of corner radius. Is it possible to apply `border-radius` for a specific corner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose which corner you want to round and pick one of the four following lines.

```
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

From W3Schools

Add a rounded border to the top-right corner of a `<div>` element:

```
div {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
}
```

Also, for some additional information I would suggest you take a look at the following:
[CSS3 Borders](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp)